# How To Change Meta Data In DomPDF Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I try to change the Producer meta data in my laravel project with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
with this code

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('export.eport_template', $data)
        ->addInfo(['Producer'=>'The Producer XYZ'])
        ->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
$tx_name = "Report_" . now()->timestamp . ".pdf";
$pdf->save(public_path() . '/storage/exports/' . $tx_name);
```

but after export, the property of the pdf on Producer is still "dompdf 0.8.6 + CPDF"
How actualy to change the Producer meta data, because in penetration testing it lead to Excessive information in PDF Header

Thanks

Comment: What is `PDF` class here? There's no such thing as "barryvdh DomPDF" and the dompdf library is currently at version 1.01.

Comment: @miken32 sorry I mean DOMPDF Wrapper for Laravel